# How to create xsd for an object

Tags: xsd, wsdl, xsd.exe

I have an method in which I need to pass parameters value some like this in the publish methods.

```
facebookclient. publish("me/events", FacebookType.class,Parameter.with("name", "Party"));
```

Instead of passing it as three parameters, I am trying to pass it as object storing these three parameters in the object record.

eg:

```
facebookclient.publish(record);
```

so that in publish method , I can get this

```
void publish(Record record)
{
String event= record.getEvent();
}
```

I am trying to create an xsd for these parameters. Kindly guide me how to do it. for me/events I can create an element in the xsd as

```
<element name="events" type="string" />
```

and refer it in an object

```
<element name="Record">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element ref="fb:events" />
            // how to specify for FacebookType.class,Parameter.with("name", "Party"))?
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

Kindly guide me, how to specify the element FacebookType.class,Parameter.with("name", "Party")) in xsd?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming this is for .NET since you are using xsd.exe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the schemagen application ([http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.wsfep.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftwbs_jaxbjava2schema.html](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wsfep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_jaxbjava2schema.html)) to do it via command line or JAXB classes (http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Invoking_schemagen_programatically.html) programmatically... this is all assuming you have you classes annotated with the appropriate annotations.